# How to create dynamic DropDownList with several complex types? ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, dynamic, razor, viewmodel

guys. I have these ViewModels:

```
public class CandidateViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IList<CourseViewModel> Courses { get; set; }
    //...
}

public class OptionViewModel
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    //...
}

public class CourseViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string SelectedCourse { get; set; }
    public IList<OptionViewModel> Options { get; set; }

    public CourseViewModel(int options)
    {
        Options.Add(new OptionViewModel(-1, string.Empty));
        for (int count = 1; count <= options; ++count)
            Options.Add(new OptionViewModel(
                count, string.Format("Option {0}", count)));

        Options.Add(new OptionViewModel(0, "Don't want it"));
    }
}
```

Well, I want to create a number of DropDownLists equals the number of Courses into CandidateViewModel. Each dropdown should be as options the OptionViewModel list of CourseViewModel instance. I need my final result like this:

```
<select name="Course1">
    <option value="-1"></option>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
    <option value="0">Don't want it</option>
</select>

<select name="Course2">
    <option value="-1"></option>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
    <option value="0">Don't want it</option>
</select>
```

However, my .cshtml page has CandidateViewModel as Model, and I can't create by "Html.DropDownListFor" trhu Razor. Can you help me, please?

Thank you so much, guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [partial view](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/105/ASP.NET-MVC-Partial-Views-and-Strongly-Typed-Custom-ViewModels) that uses desired type.

Also you may have trouble binding this model. Please take a look at this post [MVC Model Binding to List of Complex Objects](http://seesharpdeveloper.blogspot.com.br/2012/05/mvc-model-binding-to-list-of-complex.html)

Comment: Thanks, Istern. With the Partial Views I've created the DropDownLists easily. However, I have "SelectedOption" attribute on CourseViewModel (the code above is wrong, by the way, how to fix it?). When I retrieve my model thru some Action, the "SelectedOption" value is null. Wouldn't it be equals selected value from my DropDownList?

    @Html.DropDownListFor(c => c.SelectedCourse, new SelectList(Model.Options, "Number", "Description", Model.SelectedCourse)) @Model.Name

Thanks!!

Comment: @Kiwanax, as I said a model with a list of complex object can be tricky. Start with a simpler model using only one Course, see if everything works fine and then venture to the course list. All data received by the Action must be inside of a form, before debugging the mvc binding, inspect the posted data using your browser and see if the missing values are there.

Comment: Nice. I'll try it here. Thanks again!